# Is compiling user made c++ code at runtime as an extension a good idea?

Tags: c++, compilation

I am currently developing a program and would like to let end users have the ability to write c++ code that is readable by the end user so that they can verify that it is safe to run. While compiled libraries that are closed source would be supported, source code should also be supported so that the end user is able to verify that nothing malicious is present in the extensions. Public API headers would be available to developers and user code would be a sub-project in the working directory. I already have a way in mind to compile the code at runtime, I was just wondering if it is a feature that is viable.

Comment: Running any arbitrary code is a security hole.  Does your application contain any sensitive/confidential information?

Comment: @NathanOliver My code is going to require a login, but the password would be salted and stored safely, so I would say I don't have any plans to.

Comment: I could see the security becoming a concern, I would say it would be better to use a scripting language instead of a compiled one.

Comment: `ability to write c++ code that is readable` Why C++ then? Why not other more readable language? `libraries that are closed source would be supported, source code should also be supported` So you distribute sources or not?

Comment: @KamilCuk I decided to choose c++ because it is my preferred language. No specific benefit would be added. Now that I think about it, the main benefit to using c++ would be OO but that has no real use in my application. So I would agree that while this is viable, a scripting language would be the better choice.

Comment: From what I've heard, LUA integrates reasonably well into C++ applications.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's exactly what I was thinking until this idea popped up!